# How can I create directories using snapcraft?

Tags: packaging, snap

I have a file I want to copy from my snapcraft source into the .snap I am building:

```
parts:
   foo-config:
      plugin: dump
      source: .
      stage:
        - etc/foo.conf
```

If I try and build the snap and the etc/ directory does not exist I get an error. Is there a way to use the dump plugin (or otherwise) to create directories as well as copying files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stage` is going to look for `parts/$partname/install/etc/foo.conf`.  If you want to move `foo.conf` from some other directory and have it in `$SNAP/etc/foo.conf`, you'll need to use `organize`. `organize` will create the needed directories.

```
parts:
    foo-config:
        plugin: dump
        source: .
        stage:
          - etc/foo.conf
        organize:
           <path>/foo: etc/foo.conf
```